# place a file in sbt assembled uberjar

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I am creating an uberjar in `sbt` with the `sbt-assembly` plugin. This works fine however now I want to copy a particular file (`application.conf`) into the root of the finished jar. Can I do this either in the `build.sbt` script file (using *sbt script code*) OR by placing `application.conf` in a directory where it will be picked up?

Currently I use an archive manager to *doctor* the finished jar. And I suppose this configuration file (`application.conf`) probably should already be appearing in the finished jar!